# Automatically place closing curly brace on new line

Tags: autocompletion, ide

Mainstream editors usually place closing curly brace on the new line automatically while entering function bodies and conditional constructs in languages with curly braced syntactic blocks. Vim/Neovim doesn't. Which plugin provides the feature?

Mere i-mapping isn't desirable because curly braces used not only for blocks and new line shouldn't be inserted in such cases.

#### Mainstream editor

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('hello')
}
```

#### Vim/Neovim

```js
function foo() {
  console.log('hello')}
```

Comment: https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs

Comment: @filbranden that's an option. By I am using coc-pairs and they seem to be incompatible. Coc-pairs seems to be supperior in brackets automation because of its language awareness. So would like to know other solutions

Answer (score 1):

If using Coc - `formatOnType` should be enabled and special i-keybinding set, details here https://github.com/neoclide/coc-pairs/issues/13
If not - https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs